# Jupyter notebook looses connection

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am fairly new to working with python, so I am sorry if this is a naive question.

I have set up a jupyter notebook that I start through the windows terminal. I run it with python 3.9.7 in an Anaconda virtual environment. I use microsoft edge as host browser because I had problems with google chrome blocking jupyter lab.

Since yesterday, I receive an error message after opening my notebook with - jupyter lab command (which has worked for me since some weeks now). The puzzling thing is, that I can open my notebook and work in it for some minutes usually, but then this message pops up:

> *Server Connection Error: A connection to the Jupyter server could not be established. JupyterLab will continue trying to reconnect. Check
> your network connection or Jupyter server configuration.*

Unfortunately, I have really no idea why this could be, therefore I have not tried much to fix this yet. I have a stable internet connection. Simply closing the notebook and reopening it worked for some times, but after a while of working in the notebook it looses the connection again.

Has anyone experienced similar problems?

Thank you for your help and ideas!

Comment: The connection has nothing to do with you internet connection if you install jupyter-lab on your computer locally. Jupyterlab starts a server that can be reached via a local host port. By default it is `localhost:8888`. Judging from your description it seems to be related to the windows terminal. Could you please post the content of the terminal right when a disconnect happens, as an error traceback can be found there sometimes.

Comment: Additionally, if you installed anaconda anyway, have you tried to start it with the `anaconda promt` (which is a shipped with conda automatically)? Never had any issues with jupyter-lab there.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Thank you for your quick and helpful answer! It is a shame and I waited until now, but somehow ever since I postede my question here the error did not show up anymore and I couldnt post a screenshot. But anyway I realized as you suggested, that a way to avoid this in the future is to work through the anaconda prompt, which I will do from now on. Thanks a lot to you!

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue with jupyter lab my error seems the same:

> "A connection to the Jupyter server could not be established.
> JupyterLab will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network
> connection or Jupyter server configuration."

The problem for me was that I had started the program from the command line using the "jupyter-lab" command and had subsequently closed my terminal after the jupyter lab opened. Closing terminal shut down the required server. Left the terminal open and is working normally.